# How change content on click some item from list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for my bad English. I have a problem.

I have construction with button and list of span. I need then i click on item of list (some span), text of my button change on text clickable span.

If i click first span then my button change text on "Text" or second span "Text2".

```html
<button class="switcher collapsible">X1</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">                                         
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>                                       
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text2</span>
</div>
```

I have many construction like this on my page. How i connect this for id? Then if i click on span with equal class, this is change all my buttons text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use div `class` with `span` to change text of button like below. In multi-pal case `parent()` and `prev()` is your friend.

```js
$('.collapsibleContent').find('span').click(function(e) {
  let txt = $(this).text();
  $(this).parent().prev('.switcher').text(txt);
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="switcher collapsible">X1</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text2</span>
</div>
<button class="switcher collapsible">X2</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text3</span>
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for fast feedback! Like this solution, but i i have 8 constraction like this on my page, this is working for other?

Comment: Can you post relevant  HTML. It's work if there is not any specific case.

Comment: http://ba2048be.ngrok.io i cant contain this block on div. This my server url, i think u can find section with this element?

Comment: I love u! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add click event for the class `choise__block-item` (all spans of class `choise__block-item`), get the text of clicked `span` using [**text()**](https://api.jquery.com/text/) and `set` that text to the button.

```js
$('span.choise__block-item').click(function () {
    $('.switcher').text($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="switcher collapsible">X1</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">
    <span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
    <span class="choise__block-item">Text2</span>
</div>
```

Also can see the reference of [**.html()**](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Thanks for fast feedback! Like this solution, but i i have 8 constraction like this on my page, this is working for other?

Comment: *construction http://ba2048be.ngrok.io - this my server url, i think u can find section with this element?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list text using `text()` in jQuery:

```js
$('.choise__block-item').click(function(e){
    $('.switcher').text($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="switcher collapsible">X1</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">                                         
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>                                       
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for fast feedback! Like this solution, but i i have 8 constraction like this on my page, this is working for other?

Answer (score 1):

As par my understanding your requirement is to change text of button when clicked on span.

have a look below code

```js
$('.collapsibleContent > span').click(function(){
  var clickedTxt = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.box').find('.switcher').text(clickedTxt);
});
```

```css
.box{ width:300px; float:left; border:1px solid #ff0000; margin:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<button class="switcher collapsible">button1</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">                                         
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>                                       
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text2</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
<button class="switcher collapsible">button2</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">                                         
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text3</span>                                       
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text4</span>
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text5</span>
</div>
</div>


<div class="box">
<button class="switcher collapsible">button3</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">                                         
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text6</span>                                       
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text7</span>
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text8</span>
</div>
</div>


<div class="box">
<button class="switcher collapsible">X1</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">                                         
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>                                       
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text2</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for fast feedback! Like this solution, but i i have 8 constraction like this on my page, this is working for other?

Comment: this will work for all, because code is not specific to any id or class. no matter 2 span or 50.

Comment: Sorry dosnt work, this is change all my button text. I think i need specific id for all my buttons.

Comment: please share your code in snippet, so that i can understand your requirment and solve them

Comment: @SlavaCore :: have a look updated code, i think it will help you

Comment: http://ba2048be.ngrok.io i cant contain this block on div. This my server url, i think u can find section with this element?

Comment: sorry can not understand language used in application, is there any translator?.